# node js append to existing csv file all data is being appended to one cell

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am kind of new to javascript so could do with some advice. I have the below code to run once a html form is submitted with data. The correct data is being added to the existing csv file but its all being entered into the first cell of the csv. How do i go about getting the firstname and lastname into separate columns when appending to a csv.

```
app.post("/Names.html", function(request, response) {
  
let Fname = request.body.firstname
let Lname = request.body.lastname

fs.appendFile('Names.csv', Fname + Lname + '\r\n', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns should be separated with commas, so something like this:

```
fs.appendFile('Names.csv', Fname + "," + Lname + '\r\n', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
       console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
    });
```